# How do I fix error message. "Remember that ordinal parameters are 1-based!"

Tags: nhibernate, grails, hql, grails-orm

given the code snippet (please do not ask why I construct it this way...)

```
...some more Logic...
def blaParam = ['checkinable':checkinable]
def blaQuery = " AND c.product = :checkinable"
...some more Logic...
```

and

```
def paramBox = [] + blaParam
def queryBox = "" + blaQuery
def c = Bla.executeQuery("FROM Bla b WHERE 1 = 1 "+queryBox+" ", paramBox, [max:params.max])
```

I end up with a message

```
errors.GrailsExceptionResolver Remember that ordinal parameters are 1-based!
```

How do I prevent this?

Answer (score 1):

Merging the two last parameter maps worked for me:

```
Bla.executeQuery("FROM Bla b WHERE 1 = 1 "+queryBox+" ", paramBox + [max:params.max])
```

Answer (score 1):

if I change

```
def paramBox = [] + blaParam
```

to

```
def paramBox = [:] + blaParam
```

it is working